# making an async request inside useEffect hook

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, use-effect

Inside `useEffect`, `getList` function is called in which I make an async. `get` request which updates my `socialList` state with various data received. With the help of updated state, I want to display the data received.

**State**

```
    const [socialList, setSocialList] = useState([]);
```

**Code for `useEffect` hook**

```
    useEffect(() => {
        getList();
        console.log(socialList);
    }, []);
```

**Code for `getList` function**

```
    const getList = () => {
        const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
        const config = {
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "x-auth-token": `${token}`
            }
        };
        Axios.get("/api/social", config)
            .then(res =>
                res.data[0].lists.map(list => ({
                    _id: `${list._id}`,
                    link: `${list.link}`,
                    linkName: `${list.linkName}`
                }))
            )
            .then(socialList => {
                setSocialList({ socialList });
            })
            .catch(err => err.message);
    };
```

The problem with it is that when this component initially renders, `useEffect` runs, due to an async. request in the `getList` function it proceeds further, doesn't updates my state due to which I am unable to display my data. However, the state is getting updated after a while but the component doesn't re-renders.

Comment: to re-render you have to invoke setSocialList fn with new state. In you code example I don't see it

Comment: It would be better if I could see all your code

Comment: Full code :https://hastebin.com/aditaxepun.js

Comment: There may not be any triggers for re-rendering the children. `setSocialList({ socialList })` will make `socialList` an object like `{ socialList: {...} }`, yet it should be an array. Try `setSocialList(socialList)` instead.

Comment: It worked, thanx for the help :) . Very silly of me doing such mistake.

Comment: You can write a self-answer and accept it if Sami doesn't turn the comment into an answer. This might help future visitors.